# Delicate primes

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, decision-problem, primes

Inspired by [Find the largest fragile prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41648/find-the-largest-fragile-prime).

By removing at least 1 digit from a positive integer, we can get a different non-negative integer. Note that this is different to the `Remove` function in the linked question. We say a prime number is delicate if all integers generated this way are not prime. For example, \$60649\$ generates the following integers:

```
0, 4, 6, 9, 49, 60, 64, 66, 69, 604, 606, 609, 649, 664, 669, 6049, 6064, 6069, 6649
```

None of these integers are prime, therefore \$60649\$ is a delicate prime. Note that any leading zeros are removed, and that the requirement is "not prime", so \$0\$ and \$1\$ both qualify, meaning that, for example, \$11\$ is a delicate prime.

Similar to the standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rule, you are to do one of the following tasks:

- Given a positive integer \$n\$, output two distinct, consistent<sup>*</sup> values depending on whether \$n\$ is a delicate prime or not
- Given a positive integer \$n\$, output the \$n\$th delicate prime
- Given a positive integer \$n\$, output the first \$n\$ delicate primes
- Output infinitely the list of delicate primes

<sup>*</sup>: You may choose to output two sets of values instead, where the values in the set correspond to your language’s definition of truthy and falsey. For example, a Python answer may output an empty list for falsey/truthy and a non-empty list otherwise.

You may choose which of the tasks you wish to do.

You can input and output in any [standard way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and, as this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins

For reference, the first 20 delicate primes are:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 19, 41, 61, 89, 409, 449, 499, 881, 991, 6469, 6949, 9001, 9049, 9649, 9949
```

A couple more to look out for:

```
821 - False (Removing the 8 and the 1 gives 2 which is prime)
```

---

I'll offer a +100 bounty for an answer which implements one of the standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) I/Os rather than the [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) method, that either:

- is shorter than a naive [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) implementation (please include such a version as proof if one hasn't already been posted)
- or that doesn't rely on checking whether values are delicate primes or not when generating values (e.g. may use the fact that only specific digits can occur, or something else that isn't simply slapping a "loop over numbers, finding delicate primes")

This is kinda subjective as to what counts as "checking for delicate primes", so I'll use my best judgement when it comes to awarding the bounty.

Comment: The question states "given a prime number \$n\$..." but the first output option states "given a positive integer \$n\$..." If we choose the first output option, is the input guaranteed to be prime?

Comment: @RobinRyder That's a bit of confusing wording on my part. The input will always be a positive integer (not necessarily prime), the "given a prime number \$n\$..." is part of the explanation, changing now

Comment: "two distinct, consistent values depending on whether n is a delicate prime or not" - can we not use our languages truthy/falsey definition?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I’m loathe to say “no” to reasonable I/O requests, so I think I’ll say that truthy/falsey values count as distinct values, so long as one is consistently truthy and the other consistently falsey. It’s a bit unconventional, but I think that should work as best as possible

Comment: As per default consensus the outputs would have to be consistently truthy and consistently falsey, it's just they would not necessarily need be distinct - e.g. Python could return a list which is populated (possibly differently for different inputs) as a truthy result, and an empty list as a falsey result, etc.

Comment: There has been a [recent discussion about default output format for decision problems](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19202/78410). Note that the word "consistent" is used in a different sense.

Comment: Suggest 821 as a non-delicate-prime test case.  I misunderstood from the explanation that we could only remove *contiguous* digits from the test number (and didn't go-through all the numbers in the example).  It turns-out that 821 is the first example that gives a different answer (since 81 is prime) - all the other delicate primes up to 499 don't require removal of non-contiguous digits.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen 81 isn't prime (\$81 = 9\times9\$), but yeah, I'll add that in as a test case because removing the \$8\$ and the \$1\$ gives \$2\$ which is prime

Comment: Oops.  That's what I meant.  I think...

Comment: [Very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66293/66833)

Comment: Unless "delicate" is different from "Digitallly delicate" this is the wrong definition -- this looks like a "fragile" prime.

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

#### Code

Uses the **05AB1E**-encoding. Checks whether the given number is a *delicate prime* or not.

```
æpJΘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LICr3Mz/v83MzGzBAA) or [Check for all numbers between 1 and 9949](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYx6nklt@kUJiTo5CZl5JanpqUTGQoRBtqKNgpKOgp6ejAFQTqxTDpXBqkgKnkndqaoFCSUaqQl5pbhJIbXlGalEqWCQtPycnvzwzL10hs1ihpKg01UpBKeb/4WUFXudm/K/l4jIyOLSYU8m1oqQoMbkEoiOzqLhEwcgAZhhQuZmJmSUA).

### Explanation

```
æ      # Get the powerset of the number.
 p     # Check for each element whether it is a prime.
  J    # Join these numbers into one big number.
   Θ   # Check whether this joined number is equal to 1.
```

Comment: I don't think you even need `Θ` since truthy/falsey is allowed (only confirmed in comments at present).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for the heads up! The last byte is indeed solely for making sure that it outputs only 2 distinct values. I'll adjust the code when this condition has been changed in the main post.

Comment: @Adnan I’ve clarified my comment in the main post

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you use an infinite list and then take the first 20 items in your TIO, instead of just filtering on the `[1,10000]` list directly (i.e. [like this](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9yaIPPqUn/Dy8r8Pr/HwA))?

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>16</s></sup> 14 bytes

```apl
</1⍭⍎⍕(⊢,,¨)\⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfmf9qhtQvV/G33DR71rH/X2PeqdqvGoa5GOzqEVmjGPerf@r/2fpqBuZmBmYqnO9ah3R9qhFQpANWBys6GBAQA)

-2 bytes (`∊⍎¨¨ → ⍎⍕`) thanks to @ngn.

Full program that takes a single number from stdin and prints 1 (true) or 0 (false).

The trick here is how it generates all non-empty subsequences:

- `(⊢,,¨)/ str` gives all subsequences of `str` which include the last character.

```apl
  (⊢,,¨)/ '1234'
→ '1' (⊢,,¨) '2' (⊢,,¨) '3' (⊢,,¨) '4'
→ '1' (⊢,,¨) '2' (⊢,,¨) '4' '34'
→ '1' (⊢,,¨) '4' '34' '24' '234'
→ '4' '34' '24' '234' '14' '134' '124' '1234'
```

- `(⊢,,¨)\ str` applies `(⊢,,¨)/` to each prefix of `str`, giving all non-empty subsequences as a list of lists of strings.

```apl
  (⊢,,¨)\ '1234'
→ '1' ('2' '12') ('3' '23' '13' '123') ('4' '34' '24' '234' '14' '134' '124' '1234')
```

Explanation of whole code:

```apl
</1⍭⍎⍕(⊢,,¨)\⍞
             ⍞  ⍝ Take n from stdin as a string
      (    )\   ⍝ For each prefix, reduce from right by
         ,¨     ⍝   prepend the previous char to each string
       ⊢,       ⍝   and append to the previous list of strings
    ⍎⍕          ⍝ Convert nested strings to a single string,
                ⍝ and then eval it to get a simple integer vector
  1⍭  ⍝ Test each number for primality
</    ⍝ Test if the only truth is the last one
```

Comment: I'm missing something... How do we get "all possible subsets" from "all prefixes"?  I'm guessing it's "prepend the previous char to each string" but I'm not seeing it clearly.

Comment: @Jonah Added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks Bubbler.  It looks like the J equivalent of `(⊢,,¨)` is not as nice because of boxing: `([:,(];,)&>)/`.  Can you see a way to shorten it?

Comment: Actually, if you box the argument first you can do `(],,&.>)/` which is much more parallel to yours.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <sup>7</sup> 6 bytes

```
ṗ⊇ᵘṗˢȮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvaAAEj@Yvq37UtuFRU5Na7elF5f8f7pz@qKv94dYZQMbpRSfW/f8PAA)

```
ṗ⊇ᵘṗˢȮ the implicit input
ṗ      is a prime
 ⊇ᵘ    and from every unique subset
   ṗˢ  select the primes
     Ȯ and this should be a list with one element (the prime input itself)
```

Comment: If `⊇ᵘṗˢ` on its own [is a list of the primes in the unique subset](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX@8OtMx7unH560f//xibm/6MA) is there not a one-byte addition that can assert that this is `[?]`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I can't think of one, the constants don't have something with `?`. (In the answer history is a 7 byte solution exactly like yours: `⊇ᵘṗˢ[?]`.) What could work is using e.g. `60649` as both input and output with `⊇ᵘṗˢ⌋`. But I thought that would be like taking two arguments.

Comment: Hmm, indeed I'm also not sure having to give the input twice would be acceptable. (I would have thought with no `Z` argument that would be the default behaviour of Brachylog :/)

Comment: For what it's worth, `⊇ᵘṗˢ[?]` could also be `⊇ᵘṗˢ~g?`, still 7 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DŒPḌẒḄ’
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer which returns zero (falsey) if it's a delicate prime, or a non-zero integer (truthy) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//RMWSUOG4jOG6kuG4hOKAmf///zYwNjQ5)** Or see the [first twenty](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//RMWSUOG4jOG6kuG4hOKAmf/Dh8KsJDIwI/8).

#### How?

```
DŒPḌẒḄ’ - Link: n         e.g. 824                      409
D       - decimal digits       [8,2,4]                  [4,0,9]
 ŒP     - power-set            [[],[8]...,[8,2,4]]      [[],[4],...,[4,0,9]]
   Ḍ    - undecimal            [0,8,2,4,82,84,24,824]   [0,4,0,9,40,49,9,409]
    Ẓ   - is prime?            [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
     Ḅ  - from binary          32                       1
      ’ - decrement            31                       0
```

Comment: Ah, converting from binary’s a clever trick! I was trying to figure out how to shorten “is only the last element 1?”. Also, I think you can replace the last 2 bytes with `’` to decrement it and output a falsey value for delicate primes and truthy otherwise

Comment: I was thinking of that, was just waiting on your confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¥à f_°j
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=peAgZl%2bwag&input=IjYwNjQ5Ig) or [test `[0,1000)`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWY&header=cw&code=peAgZl%2bwag&input=MTAwMA)

```
¥à f_°j     :Implicit input of integer string
¥           :Is equal to
 à          :Combinations
   f        :Filter
    _       :By passing each through a function
     °      :Postfix increment, to cast to an integer
      j     :Is prime?
```

Comment: I read the language as Jelly initially, and was impressed and confused trying to figure out how it worked :/

Comment: Explanation added, @cairdcoinheringaahing.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
qjfP_sTy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzArLSC@OKTy/38lc3Olf/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

### Explanation

```
qjfP_sTy
  f       # filter
       y  # all subsets of input
   P_sT   # with a primality test
 j        # join result of filter on newlines
q         # check if it equals input
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>25</sup> 23 bytes

*-2 thanks to Jonah!*

Returns a list containing either 1 being truthy or 0 otherwise.

```
1</@p:(#~2#:@i.@^#)&.":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrBCgIxDETvfsXQgruFbk3XWtugUBA8efIDvIiL60Xvgr9e0w3My2Qmr6pcN@HI6GBBYNHgcLpeztUfNuXDvf6Nmsvsyk2btVNczepxf77RS/N1ZVJkMDt4kjEYGKPF1mJnsbfwXpQtguwoSs1TQ2jIgpQkz7k9hCh3zK3KRC2mxceFktc/)

#### How it works

```
1</@p:(#~2#:@i.@^#)&.":
                   &.": convert the number to a string
      (  2      ^#)      2 ^ length
          #:@i.@         enumerated and to base 2
       #~                select from the string based on the bit mask
                   &.": convert from strings to numbers
1   p:                  primes -> 1, non-primes -> 0
                         so in the delicate prime case, we have
                         (2^L) - 1 zeros and one 1 for the input itself
 </@                    reduce from left to right with less-than
                         (so last position is 1, everything else 0)
```

Comment: Really like `</@` here.  Since it's a decision problem you can get [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYrBCgIxDETvfsXQgruFbk3XWtugUBA8efIDvIiL60Xvgr9e0w3My2Qmr6pcN@HI6GBBYNHgcLpeztUfNuXDvf6Nmsvsyk2btVNczepxf77RS/N1ZVJkMDt4kjEYGKPF1mJnsbfwXpQtguwoSs1TQ2jIgpQkz7k9hCh3zK3KRC2mxceFktc/ "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 53 bytes

```
^
;
+%`;(.)
$1;$'¶$`;
.+
$*
%A`^.?$|^(..+)\1+$
^1+¶+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcO7DYAgEADQ/uY4InjJRRQ/hMJYuYQhWFjYWBhL53IAFsN7ybuP57z2ovSaSoQApFLQbABtwCp/mAIwAdaglhR5xjdqZjKbJYRoKX@EpbjGg7OylZ10speDHOUkvf8B) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^
;
+%`;(.)
$1;$'¶$`;
```

Generate all subsequences of the input.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert then to unary.

```
%A`^.?$|^(..+)\1+$
```

Delete the ones that aren't prime, but don't delete the newlines. (A multiline replace also works, but is harder to format an explanation for.)

```
^1+¶+$
```

Check that the original input was prime but none of the proper subsequences were.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>173</s> 170 bytes

```scala
n=>(s"$n".indices.toSet.subsets.filter{x=>1<x.size&x.size<s"$n".size}.map(_.toSeq.sorted.map(""+n).mkString.toInt).toSet+n).filter{x=>x>1&2.to(x/2).forall(x%_>0)}==Set(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVA9T8MwEN37K04WVLaIjBPSNKmaSDAgMTCVEalyWxcZXCfELoqo@tvDOQUqJoZ7d37vPu3W0si@Xr2qtYdHqS2oziu7cXDbNHAYjT6kge0MHqyHsoK7ujZKWih7W1bUkQtLuLYbvVaO@3qhPHf7lVPe8a02XrWHrqzieced/lTjk5ufqkJ45DvZ0OVQ@c5d3Xq1GShCrizju7eFb7V9QR3Hs9OAIJx7d1U8TlCg3XWCfN1KY2h3uawEO5YlplPLeoAG23hjKXlq92pG2AiAJBHcRDCJYBpBHKMVEaToM7Q8xCJAGqBAyHPkiyIkpBm@syJIhRCBFkOcDYg8XtcY7SmJgLDhIPytnx221H4fxMIeZzoT2OAPR57tvTTuZ2MBMaSQCEgnEAsB@TT7nfTfoGP/BQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>163</s> 154 bytes

```r
function(x,n=nchar(x),s=sum)(a=apply(!expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),n)),1,function(v)(y=s((x%/%10^(n:1-1)%%10)[v]*10^(s(v):1-1)))&s(!y%%1:y)==2))[1]&!s(a[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/RboMwDEXf@xVBFZU9pVvcdZWKlC9BrIogjEg0jWLawtczYNoextuVfc@RHUfHl8q2rjSdvYTorlaP9d2Xnbt56KXXvmxMhB4la75fEYw2IbQDJLYPxlevX9FVEG2A1nEHKiOUHlGS/LM8EAbNAH36lpL6BJ/RnjCdMuaP4mUe8VRapog7hmSYltmAWh8Qcyp2CYPJ91Tg@lo4qdPxjGIrliAcCyN@K2KpbNYQHd6PHzO0hBnyt24NPhtXNsA/D1NGSim5kuHsqV3kTtT2@U/Bm/Eb)

Checks for primes among the numbers formed by removing all combinations of digits from x.
The first combination is removal of *no* digits: this must be TRUE, and all other prime tests must be FALSE.

Commented:

```r
is_delicate_prime=
function(x,                     # x = number to test
 n=nchar(x),                    # n = number of digits of x
 s=sum)                         # s = alias to sum() function
(a=                             # a = matrix of all prime-tests:
 apply(                         #     apply the function v to each of...
  !expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),n)),   # all combinations of n of TRUE/FALSE...
  1,                            #     row-by-row...
  function(v)                   #     defining the output of v as:
   (y=s((x%/%10^(n:1-1)%%10)    #       the digits of x...
    [v]                         #       (considering only the elements chosen by v)... 
       *10^(s(v):1-1)))         #       multiplied by 10^((v-1)..0)...
   &s(!y%%1:y)==2))             #       tested for primality AND non-zero
[1]                             # Finally, output TRUE if a[1] is TRUE...
   &!s(a[-1])                   # and the sum of all other elements of a are FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 54 bytes

```
Select[FromDigits/@Subsets@@RealDigits@#,PrimeQ]=={#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg1JzW5JNqtKD/XJTM9s6RY3yG4NKk4taTYwSEoNTEHIuigrBNQlJmbGhhra1utXKv2H8jLK4lW1rVLc1COVatzLCpKrKwzMuCCiEMNDUrMS091MDQAAp202Nj/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>139</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>145</s></sup> 142 bytes

Added 36 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger).
Saved 5 bytes thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)!!!

```python
lambda n,R=range:all((g<2or any(g%i<1for i in R(2,g)))-(`g`==n)for g in{int(''.join(n[j]for j in R(len(n))if i>>j&1))for i in R(1,2**len(n))})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBNb8IwDIbv/ApftsQoTG0ohSLCceeJa4dEoB9L1aVVmgua9ts7p@UwaddFsmM/rxM76e/@o7NyrNT72OrPa6HBipNy2tblXrct5/VBdg60vfP6yRziihIDxsKJS1Ej4opf6otSFoNSk/JlrOeMvTSdsdzmzTkIzXykLQkhmgrM8dg8x4i/7ouFXC4fFd84OsXZqzYtA8He9DAwXBQ9KMilgLWAjYCtgDgmywQktKdkuxBHwSXBZeR2O@JZFgqSlPI0C1IWRQFHU5xOnvh5EebxYR7@p812biWJStrXxNbbuXVCLKF48z9j4H4BtAZ6bcUH77hHnMitc668eeJ8GrLoEZSCYRJ7Rz8PXgCD1RGYgEGAyx9HzuMP)

Inputs an integer as a string and returns `True` if it's a delicate prime or `False` otherwise.

Comment: Goddammit! I was just about to post my Python 3 solution, which is almost the exact same! The `R=range` trick is genius. You can replace the `and ` with `*` since `True == 1` in Python and truthy/falsey values are allowed.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that your solution isn't actually correct, I'm still trying to work out why exactly...

Comment: You're not checking that the initial input number itself is prime.

Comment: @pxeger Ooops, thought we only had prime inputs - fixing that...

Comment: @pxeger All fixed and nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>98</s>  95 bytes

Expects `n` as a string. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
n=>[...n].reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>(g=k=>y%--k?g(k):(p+=q=y>1&k<2,y))(y+=x))],[p=0])|q/p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBDoIwEEDRq8xGmElLLS6VwYMQFg0UomBbQA1NvDti3Pz8vLt5m6WZb@GZOd/arePNcVkppVytZtu@Goto5Ep/NPIX9TABI5fY88BlPGTZcO1xoDMGwRPHMk@G4iQjEUbBK1Etq8C6ps90DFvnZ3TAkF/AQQG51no/IQi63QWkKUGSQOPd4kerRt@jo@0L)

#### How?

We compute the powerset of the digits of `n` in such a way that the order is preserved and `n` itself is computed last. The result is true if the only prime among the resulting integers is the last one.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>146</s></sup> 144 bytes

*-2 bytes by removing redundant parentheses*

I was also working on a very similar answer just before [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9481/noodle9) posted theirs, and I combined ideas from that to get this ([upvote it!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211382)). That one is now quite different because they initially had a broken one, so I thought I'd post mine.

```python
lambda s,R=range:(l:=len(s))*all((g!=int(s))^(g>1)&all(g%k for k in R(2,g))for g in{int(''.join(s[j]for j in R(l)if i>>j&1))for i in R(1,2**l)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHBboMwDL33K7zDmrjKJhJogErhI3ptO4muhUEzQIEdJsS3MweOuzSSnednx35Jut/hq23CpHNzYc6zzb@vtxx6cTQub8r7gduDsfeG94i73FrOyxdTNYOPP3iZSdx6tnx9QNE6eEDVwJErUSL6uKR49OWMvddtRW1O9cUn6rXQYlVAlWX1Vq4HqpWXQu12FiecneHs/KPi6JOBWJAMGW5uHRg4KQGhgL2AWICUZKmAiHZNlngceBd5l5JLEuLT1BdEmmKd@lQaBJ4OFqwXT/xl4@UMXg4PqLOAf8PidaCitKKMIhwSH1JJGK9CIuIjwvtnREmt9TPS8LABWj29QMH7wfEBcWE655@6YOMwwVsGYz/B6E58ucStQzAGrm1r6e8uE8P5Dw)

Explanation:

```
lambda s,R=range:(l:=len(s))*all((g!=int(s))^(g>1)&all(g%k for k in R(2,g))for g in{int(''.join(s[j]for j in R(l)if i>>j&1))for i in R(1,2**l)})

lambda s        :                                                                                                                                       function
        ,R=range                                                                                                                                        alias `range` built-in to `R`
                                                                                   {            s[j]for j in R(l)if i>>j&1  for i in R(1,2**l)}         compute the power-set (excluding the empty set)
                                                                                    int(''.join(                          ))                            convert each list of digits to an integer
                             all(                                          for g in                                                            )        check the integers for primality
                                                    all(g%k for k in R(2,g))                                                                            check for factors in the number
                                              (g>1)&                                                                                                    makes sure 0 and 1 aren't treated as prime
                                 (g!=int(s))^                                                                                                           ensure the number itself is prime
                 (l:=len(s))*                                                                                                                           store the length in `l`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/), 139 bytes

```
def f(n):s=str(n);l=len(s);return p(n)*all(~-p(g)for g in{int(''.join(s[j]for j in R(l)if i>>j&1))for i in R(1,2**l-1)})
R=range;p=is_prime
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytkU1uwyAQhfc-xawKRKTyX-yQiBwi29SqIhtHWC5GQFaWe_YOpLtuizTD43ugGWBQI4zUsJOXPjgU51nOylDPzk6FpzNgEe7u80y_95Y-2Lg4eIA2qzaBEvI-LRp336YuGhMacKUz0yPoy2V6K1g6oF-84OVuN-8LtrHsKt3dPNTZSu0_rdNfKsucpOTjWbZ1T4AnVVSEZYMFCbeSQ8XhwKHlUBQYgkONc4NxjDqPqY5JYDoekQsRN9QNrhsRLZHnEedJNykj77LYZIhN0j9l2lepEmmJc4Wsal-la2Q16sP_tMFOGeDweFuzhBQjDSzBfnFO9QEtmvocLAMpwScTnw8_YyRr2GB_gdVvsLrb75FuI-wHUpV4AQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Port of my Python answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  181 bytes

**Using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and a golfed recipe for `powerset`.**

```
lambda s,R=range:all(p(int(''.join(t)),R)for t in sum(([*combinations(s,k)]for k in R(1,len(s))),[]))>p(int(s),R)
from itertools import*
p=lambda n,R:any(n%i<1for i in R(2,n))or 2>n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFfT8IwEH/fp7gXQwuN2RCQLc6PwMNekZiiLVa269JWE2P87PO6gQSMXnK3@//7Xdd@hBeLN50uH7paNttnCV5UpZO4U4Wsa9Yyg4GNRtev1iALnIuKa@sggEHwbw1j6/GTbbYGZTAWPfNizzexYx87KpaJWiHznCbXG87vh4U@7kna8oCJoiokfjC8MndZHDbD8FQg5xRO7zHRzjZggnLB2tqDaVrrwrhbQQl5Pk@TZ1WbJxmUp8R6KuBGwFzArYAsI80FzOi7IF1GP41mFk1OZrmkfJ7HhtmC4kUeS3maxnTa@4veUn6TRIIYCfbPRBeueJEAiZa1V4@t9SaYdyUOMaqdjDHxSkXaNxo9LPjhPMwfSzaAZj44RtefKlFa1/8O@Et6RDgiFjASgDz51XHiNCkh6@uK0mcs/mcwAB1P/Rvo2DEAHYZXb81WObAalHPW@QI@v4CRaoRJ9HXLR9f0zI0M7HzP5Jz/5RuLC1jOu28)

Expects input as a string.

The function `p` returns `True` if its input is not prime, and `False` if it is prime; the main function returns `(forall t, p(t)) > p(s)` where `t` takes all the "subvalues" of `s`. The only way for booleans to satisfy this inequality is `True > False`, which means all `t` are nonprimes and `s` is not nonprime.

*Disclaimer: There were already two python answers when I posted this one.*

Comment: Don’t worry about existing answers. So long as they aren’t exact duplicates, there’s no issue and it’s always interesting to see different approaches to the same challenge