# Find the largest recurring prime

Tags: code-challenge, primes

Inspired by [Find the largest fragile prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41648/find-the-largest-fragile-prime)

A recurring prime (or whatever you choose to call it) is a prime that, when removing leading digits, always remain prime regardless of how many digits are removed.

```
for example
6317 is a recurring prime because...
317 is a recurring prime because...
17 is a recurring prime because...
7 is a prime
```

727 is a prime but not a recurring prime because 27 is not a prime.

**Goal**
Like the original question, your score is the largest recurring prime found by your program/ algorithm.

**Rules**
I copied these from the original question

```
You may use any language and any third-party libraries.  
You may use probabilistic primality tests.  
Everything is in base 10.
```

Edit: Welp... turns out I have not factored in adding zeros in this question. Although I have not thought about adding 0 at first but it indeed satisfy my requirements, since removing a digit in front of (any number of) zeros skips many digits of prime tests and returns trivially true if the last few digits is a recurring prime. To make this question less of a "zero spam" but also reward strategic use of zeros, **at most 2 consecutive zeros can be present in your answer**. (Sorry to Level River St who asked me this)

Comment: Are numbers where some digits are zero allowed? See my answer.

Comment: @a'_' I think the point is that primes with multiple consecutive zeros are fairly trivial to find and not very interesting. For example I found  9000000000000007 manually. I have since deleted my answer.

Comment: @a'_' I do not mean that, but this question is made to reward understanding and strategic use of number properties that these primes have.  What I want is some creative way to list/extend existing recurring primes (see the original question). Because of my oversight adding zeros are not explicitly banned but I do want their use to be strategic enough to provoke thought. Hence the 2-0 requirement.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I am terribly sorry to change the requirements after you posted your answer, you can keep your answer here for reference instead of just deleting it.

Comment: It's OK, it didn't take long to do. I will leave it deleted. Your new ruling is interesting, as it has a connection with base 1000. for example `9007` is admissible, which is `97` when written in base 1000.

Comment: Not that Python is my first language, but that username...

Comment: If there is no time limit, I could have written a program taking an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: @Akanga well that's 100% normal for this website; your program still has to output an output in a finite enough amount of time for you to actually see the output.

Comment: Just for interest (and because ovs seems to have found the largest prime admissible under the rules as they stand), I checked numbers of the form `A*10**B+C` where A and C are in the range `1..9` and B<1000 and found that `1E999+7` is the largest such prime in this range.

Comment: @LuisMendo And the winning answer is in Python ...

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 79 digits (probably optimal)

A simple depth first search that allows up to two consecutive zeros.

```python
from sympy.ntheory.primetest import isprime

def dfs(n=0, k=1):
    yield n
    if 100*n > k:
        yield from dfs(n, k*10)
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isprime(k*i + n):
            yield from dfs(k*i + n, k*10)

l = 1
for prime in dfs():
    if prime > l:
        d = len(str(prime))
        print(f'{d} digits: {prime}')
        l = 10**d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BjsIgGITvPMXcpKwxoIdNTOq7uAGUtP1pgAsxPnuXYrWayAX4Z@YbGHO6ejpMkw1@QMzDmHeUrsaHvBuDG0wyMcENow9li3XEmDYW2kZOrdyia1VzZCgrO9NrUD07CyWlIJzQPdTVUbtqvqSFkk3VrQ9wcIRwpovhaluENVl4Sz3vhMMP6E38gl5MzwLWo4Vic0eFzD2zbYEU@mN8Qr9idcn0hnhMgVe5aV5auVPidnPTd2h3cSkecaum@2Z11VYphH7/R8G2@N1/Pv8vmHM3Tf8) [Validate the result!](https://tio.run/##rY47DsIwEESv4gNQTGxnEzqOADWisFAkUpgCuUOc3awVhAAZ@ZdmvLvzZmRr3GWyxs1n4/3@Nl/dkdVOB7ETd7UREmCl5RnxGjTe4xb42Ajf@wj8nobITSF27VmjBm9/PQUk7ATRpRHWDErnYayZJG/58FBEE8p4VRqg4oQsj@iKDAWyJlYZ7MOpMrt4DfHGgq65QaK9Qwd4ja9glabHyfsn)

Finds `200400201909005006060042636079002004200130030090050030780060900408062003` (72 digits) in 8 seconds on TIO. I let the program run on my computer a little longer and the highest recurrent prime it found is `7030560306007020600400306654060053003909007054300609009069003056030702030330347` ([validation](https://tio.run/##rYw5DsIwEEWv4gNQfGW8KB1HgBpRWCgSKUyB3CHObmxCxBaMt8LLvPn/GW2Pg9F2PGjnNufxZHf@NsOWrdlFrRj3h@4Xpmd@Mf86PP8KrxPhfZb4JOIbERZgDyxy@WvRI7JCZCsR3xPwL8ITMiIlpJAU8zw5mZ6lrLDnOXmRW5BAdoejpCXKarK0V1okFFd54MVt36kTdKhWhKlaIoEmHkIrUyCtXKKl7AFb6RSaCq97524)). The program actually completed after finding this number, so this is probably the longest prime meeting the challenges requirement.

Note that sympys [`isprime`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=isprime#sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime) could theoretically return `true` for pseudoprimes `>2^64`, though no examples are known as of now.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 digits

only considers numbers without zeros

```python
from sympy.ntheory.primetest import isprime

def dfs(n=0, k=1):
    yield n
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isprime(k*i + n):
            yield from dfs(k*i + n, k*10)

l = 1
for prime in dfs():
    if prime > l:
        print(f'{len(str(prime))} digits: {prime}')
        l *= 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LDoMgEEX3fMXdFa1pNN2Z2H9pIrQTcTDAhhi/3QK1j9lA7lzOYYnhafm679rZGT7OS7xweCrr4mVxNKugfADNi3Xp8CUSYlQao/aSh7bBNHRVL5AmkjIjuNy1dSAQw935oWTXdO3RykP6A5NTTTiD/5Y/VPlUFh2lJKsTRwiDAZ3IjgLJnlw7IIn@jm8wP2yKOEh9Wo1i6YOTpVNVG0Z6UPA91pJsp@r7xqBOonbfXw) [Validate the result!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJBpI5qYGKjgoVJvrKBgDsSGIsASTRhDKDEqbwxhmcJYpgmmGxDZE5hih8MxQuSZofDN0ASMMEUNMIWMsYmbYBC2wipphFzbHIW6KXaI29v9/AA)

Finds `357686312646216567629137` in less then a second on TIO.

Comment: Your 24-digit prime without zeros is indeed known to be the biggest possible such answer: https://oeis.org/A024785

Comment: If the search halts and there are no bugs in your code, that could be considered a proof that it's actually optimal.

Comment: Made an iterative version [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwEETv@oohJ6kNxiaHQmj6IyEHU0nxUmslJEExId/uyHZrh3YvgqfZndkNQ@48H8bRRu@QBheGinNnfByqEMmZbFIGueBjedKMhBDaWGibpDoKlEq5/fzCCefDHm@XGWkTcjehZo/mImb23VFvFvHSNxUX0Yyq4INUK9eFz0MWjhc0tVh/BzK9Bm/A@ggCMWLLVyObui4djHfo4l@rzW8qsr@7SCoyjVfwH8m6VtWGYFg/Cf/plpg/Oq3KfVwJX4s109OpJmt8wG1uJQdnaXe33rBMOUpS6g5NV8rpiBvdd5vjNJfG8QE "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I guess so, but I'm not sure how interesting this find is outside of this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
Ｆ37⊞υιＦυＦＥ⁹⁺⊕κι¿⬤…²Ｉκ﹪Ｉκλ«κＤ⎚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5LCsIwEF23pxi6mkCEqguRrqRuBAvFG4Q2/eA0Kfm4Ec8ekyK4mXm8H6@bhOm0oBAGbQCL46lg0Ho7oecwsyrfaM9g@41Y8cyhJW/xpjojF6mc7PHJkpkxmAfACxE@hBolHjjUwrooR73RvSeNP4IDJf87z1ozq8RUeXb1y4oJ1CSF2VAqvEtr41Gji6ticl@W7D8yJT8hhN2Lvg) Finds all zero-free recurring primes, but is inefficient, so the TIO link is limited to just under 60 seconds' worth of primes. Explanation:

```
Ｆ37⊞υι
```

Start with the two possible last digits of all recurring primes (except the trivial `2` and `5`).

```
Ｆυ
```

Perform a breadth first search of recurring primes as they are found.

```
ＦＥ⁹⁺⊕κι
```

Prefix each non-zero digit to the prime so far.

```
¿⬤…²Ｉκ﹪Ｉκλ«
```

Use trial division to find out whether this is a new prime.

```
κＤ⎚⊞υκ
```

If it is then output it and add it to the list of recurring primes.