# How many partitions contain only perfect squares?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, combinatorics, set-partitions

Given a non-negative integer or a list of digits, determine in how many ways can the number be formed by concatenating square numbers, which may have leading zeroes.

## Examples

```
input -> output # explanation
164 -> 2 # [16, 4], [1, 64]
101 -> 2 # [1, 01], [1, 0, 1]
100 -> 3 # [100], [1, 00], [1, 0, 0]
1 -> 1 # [1]
0 -> 1 # [0]
164900 -> 9 # [1, 64, 9, 0, 0], [1, 64, 9, 00], [1, 64, 900], [16, 4, 900], [16, 4, 9, 0, 0], [16, 4, 9, 00], [16, 49, 0, 0], [16, 49, 00], [16, 4900]
```

## Rules

- Standard Loopholes Apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: [Sandbox Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13208/68942)

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits?

Comment: why is 1 -> 1 but 0 -> 0?

Comment: @Jonah Typo... xD

Comment: @totallyhuman Sure.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒṖḌÆ²Ạ€S
```

A monadic link taking a list of digits and returning a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pz3c0XO47dCmh7sWPGpaE/z///9oEx0DIDSJBQA)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pz3c0XO47dCmh7sWPGpaE/z/6J7D7UBGFhA/apijoGun8KhhbuT//9HRhjoKZjoKJrE6CiCmgY6CIYJpAGaCCDDLBCKIohqKYmMB).

#### How?

```
ŒṖḌÆ²Ạ€S - Link: list of digits              e.g. [4,0,0,4]
ŒṖ       - all partitions                         [[4,0,0,4],[4,0,[0,4]],[4,[0,0],4],[4,[0,0,4]],[[4,0],0,4],[[4,0],[0,4]],[[4,0,0],4],[4,0,0,4]]
  Ḍ      - convert from decimal list (vectorises) [[4,0,0,4],[4,0,   4 ],[4,    0,4],[4,      4],[   40,0,4],[   40,    4],[    400,4],     4004]
   Æ²    - is square? (vectorises)                [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,   1 ],[1,    1,1],[1,      1],[    0,1,1],[    0,    1],[      1,1],        0]
     Ạ€  - all truthy? for €ach                   [        1,          1,          1,          1           0,            0,          1,        0]
       S - sum                                    5
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 135 bytes

```hs
s x=any((x==).(^2))[0..x]
c(a:b:x)=a*10+b:x
c x=x
h[x]=1>0
h x=(s.head)x
f x@(_:_:_)|y<-until h c x=f(tail y)+f(c y)
f x=sum[1|any s x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU7BCsIwFLv3K3rw8OrqaEUEhxX/o1Spc6XDrYjd4A327/WNHJJAQhJ9/nTDUErmaHxaANAYUcPjKIRVdY2OteCbV4PC@L1WFSnWUhZZtOiMvikWyUKuY@ffAlngeIdnQxDrcj3MaeoHHvnWCTB5MouoArREW9bkebR6pWlOF1wZfZ/M99enaReslmd5kheppHLlDw)

Probably not well golfed yet but this is a surprisingly difficult problem

Answer (score 6):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 88 bytes

```hs
f x=sum[0.5|y<-mapM(\c->[[c],c:" "])x,all((`elem`map(^2)[0..read x]).read).words$id=<<y]
```

Defines a function `f` that takes a string and returns a float.
Very slow.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvRCsIgGEDhV/mRXShsYlFBob3BnsCMiTqSdA1d5KB3t9HdufjOQ@enC6HWEYrI7ygZPX5X3kU99/hmuquURrXmggApUlodAsaDCy4Om8D3PdkGmpy2UBT5B6GfV7K58VZwvqoatZ9AwJz8tEADI6Dd6XBmDNUf)

### Explanation

I'm using [my Haskell tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98446/32014) for computing all partitions of a string with `mapM` and `words`.
The snippet `mapM(\c->[[c],c:" "])x` replaces every character `'c'` of a string `x` with either the one-element string `"c"` or the two-element string `"c "`, and returns the list of all possible combinations.
If I take one of the results, `y`, concatenate it and call `words` on the result, it will be split at the spaces inserted by `mapM`.
In this way I obtain all partitions of `x` into contiguous substrings.
Then I just count those results where each partition element is a perfect square (by finding it in the list `[0,1,4,9,..,x^2]`).
A caveat is that each partition is counted twice, with and without a trailing space, so I take the sum of `0.5`s instead of `1`s; this is why the result type is a float.

```hs
f x=                       -- Define f x as
 sum[0.5|                  -- the sum of 0.5 for
  y<-                      -- every y drawn from
  mapM(\c->[[c],c:" "])x,  -- this list (explained above)
                           -- (y is a list of one- and two-element strings)
  all(...)                 -- such that every element of
                 id=<<y]   -- concatenated y
          .words$          -- split at spaces satisfies this:
                           -- (the element is a string)
   (...).read              -- if we convert it to integer
    `elem`                 -- it is an element of
    map(^2)                -- the squares of
    [0..read x]            -- the numbers in this list.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
lf!f!sI@sjkY2T./
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lf%21f%21sI%40sjkY2T.%2F&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+6%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+0%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%2C+6%2C+4%2C+9%2C+0%2C+0%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>148</s> <s>139</s> <s>135</s> 134 bytes

10 bytes thanks to Arnold Palmer.

```python
def f(a):
 s=[a[:1]]
 for i in a[1:]:s=sum([[x+[i],x[:-1]+[x[-1]*10+i]]for x in s],[])
 return sum({n**.5%1for n in x}=={0}for x in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYvLCsMgFET3foWbgia3RekDKvgll7sINFIXNUUTsIR8u42rknQ1zJk578/4HMK5lEfvuBOdNIwnix0aTcS4GyL33AfeoTZkkk3TSyDmFj1BRnPU1GLGNRqtWk9UhVyFRIAkGY/9OMW1rt4cmuZ0Pej6CfWTF2tntfwcWd7Rh1E4gRpucIE7KFAkJdvyHVGg/8jO2rS6lS8)

Comment: I'd double check this, but I believe it works.  [140 characters.](https://tio.run/##ZY3NCsIwDIDvPkUvQrtl0uIPOOiTxBwiYzhwXZkTKmPPXtcdxOnx@5Iv8a/h1rl9rO0l3rm9Viy4fDxbObos2x23RtRdL5xonAiTtaOeEofEXrJSG28/GaMpiV0lUo8YcsZiNhCwLAzlGGakzOjFE9H3pWVFESCprkem6PvGDbKWaOAEBziDBk3p38r/GA3mz/xUK0qz@AY "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: I goofed and left a space between `%1` and `for`...

Comment: Replacing `[[a[0]]]` with `[a[:1]]` will save a byte

Comment: Together we outgolfed Haskell.

Comment: Best part is that it was, in part, thanks to sets, which I had never used until you posted on my [turtle answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132933/is-it-a-turtle-prime/132951#132951) yesterday.

Comment: So we outgolfed each other.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>173</s> 163 bytes

```python
lambda s:len([l for l in[''.join(sum(zip(s,[','*(n>>i&1)for i in range(len(s))]+['']),())).split(',')for n in range(2**~-len(s))]if {int(x)**.5%1for x in l}=={0}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvRCoIwFIDh@55iN7VzlskW1UWgL2JeGLlazDmcgSX26msLQrr84fvts7@1ZutldvK6as6Xirijrg0Umsi2I5ooU1Ca3ltlwD0aeCkLLiloQhmYPFcrgdGp4EhXmWsN8XaI5Tp8JSaAiKmzWvUQpi82M94y9t78DiXJqEwPAzKW7pci2iFaPWXZyKcSve0CIBKo4ILiYs7D7i85p@g/)

Edit: Saved 10 bytes due to ArnoldPalmer

Comment: Can you save a byte by using `.5` instead of `0.5`?

Comment: You can.  You can also save some bytes with the same trick I pulled on Leaky Nun's Python 3 post.  Also, your answer didn't print the number of elements, but the elements themselves, so I added that in.  If you want to keep the output you have, it's minus an extra 5 bytes.  [163 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcvRCoIwFIDh@55iN7VzlskW1UWgL2JeGLlazDmcgSX26msLQrr84fvts7@1ZutldvK6as6Xirijrg0Umsi2I5ooU1Ca3ltlwD0aeCkLLiloQhmYPFcrgdGp4EhXmWsN8XaI5Tp8JSaAiKmzWvUQpi82M94y9t78DiXJqEwPAzKW7pci2iFaPWXZyKcSve0CIBKo4ILiYs7D7i85p@g/ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice trick with set comprehension, Arnold.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 141 bytes

```
Count[FreeQ[IntegerQ/@Sqrt[FromDigits/@#],1<0]&/@(FoldPairList[TakeDrop,s,#]&/@Flatten[Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[Length[s=#]],1]),1>0]&
```

**input** (a list of digits)

> [{1,6,4}]

Comment: I think this gives the wrong answer for 1649: I count three partitions that make squares (namely `{1,64,9}`, `{16,4,9}` and `{16,49}`) but your function returns 4.

Comment: Also, I've noticed you using constructions like `Table[(function of s[[i]]),{i,Length[s=(stuff)]}]` a few times; you can usually golf this down to `(function of #)&/@(stuff)`.

Comment: @Notatree you are absolutely right! I made many changes, followed your instructions and it works like a charm! thanks